# Convert list of string to List of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of string as below

```
['40799\t1890\t11-16-15\n', '40800\t1890\t11-17-15\n', '40801\t1890\t11-18-15\n', '40802\t1890\t11-19-15\n']
```

Want to convert as below

```
 [('40799',1890,'11-16-15'), ('40800',1890,'11-17-15'), ('40801',1890,'11-18-15'), ('40802',1890,'11-19-15')]
```

Tab is the separator for each column. I am able to convert using some loop. But would like to know if it is possible to convert the list using a single command as the list may have lot of items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a list of strings, into a list of tuples containing integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554649/converting-a-list-of-strings-into-a-list-of-tuples-containing-integers)

Comment: @KegsRo But its not a list of tuples containing integers

Comment: @KegsRO ok i guess it does contain integers, but its not the same as that question

Comment: "as the list may have lot of items" you can use a list comprehension, but this will not make it faster than a loop, and the number of lines in the loop are independent of the number of items in the lists, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> data = ['40799\t1890\t11-16-15\n', '40800\t1890\t11-17-15\n', '40801\t1890\t11-18-15\n', '40802\t1890\t11-19-15\n']
>>> [(x, int(y), z) for x, y, z in (line.split() for line in data)]
[('40799', 1890, '11-16-15'), ('40800', 1890, '11-17-15'), ('40801', 1890, '11-18-15'), ('40802', 1890, '11-19-15')]
```

Comment: Is this method(below one as well) really different from using a loop when speed is considered?

Comment: @sjd Everything will have to end up using a loop, in terms of speed you should probably be processing and outputting lines one by one to a new file but im not sure how your thing is structured

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = ['40799\t1890\t11-16-15\n', '40800\t1890\t11-17-15\n', '40801\t1890\t11-18-15\n', '40802\t1890\t11-19-15\n']

print [tuple(s.split()) for s in lst]
```

**output:**

```
[('40799', '1890', '11-16-15'), ('40800', '1890', '11-17-15'), ('40801', '1890', '11-18-15'), ('40802', '1890', '11-19-15')]
```

Comment: Thanks ! i can see both are same. This looks prettier as all items being string is ok for me.

Comment: @sjd Then why did you post your output without them all being strings, next time ask the right question

Comment: @MaheshKaria please dont use `_` as variable name

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = ['40799\t1890\t11-16-15\n', '40800\t1890\t11-17-15\n', '40801\t1890\t11-18-15\n', '40802\t1890\t11-19-15\n']
>>> [tuple(line.split()) for line in data]
[('40799', '1890', '11-16-15'), ('40800', '1890', '11-17-15'), ('40801', '1890', '11-18-15'), ('40802', '1890', '11-19-15')]
```

Comment: I gave you upvote because OP now said they don't care about having all strings output even though original output wanted 2nd index to be an integer

Comment: However PEP8 says not to use `l` as variaable name, you should fix this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've fixed it. However, it would have been better if you there was an explanation along with a downvote. Please make it a habit. Good societies are formed when there is help available for correcting the incorrect, instead of just a verdict.